# WebMethod throws "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am getting error on this line: 
`using (SqlDataReader reader =cmd.ExecuteReader())`

I am working on AJAX cascading Drop Down Example in ASP.Net and below is my code.  I am unable to run the code due to error

> Incorrect syntax near '='. near   using (SqlDataReader reader =cmd.ExecuteReader())

Code

```
 [WebMethod]
public AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetDropDownCountry1(string knownCategoryValues)
{
   // select CountryId, Country from Country where Status='Active'
   // string query = "SELECT Country, CountryId FROM Country";
    string query = "select [CountryName], [CountryId] from Countries";
    List<AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue> countries = GetData(query);
    return countries.ToArray();
}

private List<AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue> GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    List<AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue> values = new List<AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                values.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue
                {
                    name = reader[0].ToString(),
                    value = reader[1].ToString()
                });
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are `CountryId` and `StateId` stored in database? as `int` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: I would suggest running `SQL Profiler` and see what wrong with generated queries.

Comment: or print your `query` and run it against sql server

Comment: CountryId and StateId is in int format. @ughai

Comment: After putting '{0}' the values filling into country and next state and city will not loading. @ughai

Comment: i run the query into sql and its working fine. @ughai

Comment: If your printed query is working, You might have to run a profiler as per suggestion from Evaldas

Comment: Ya i did not tried using sql parameters because its confusing me. @ughai

Comment: Can you update your answer and resolve my error. @ughai

Answer (score 0):

```
string state = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)["StateId"];
string query = string.Format("select [CityName], [CityId] FROM Cities where StateId = {0}", state);
```

If state is a string like "CA" then this will generate the SQL statement "select [CityName], [CityId] FROM Cities where StateId = CA", which is not valid.  Values passed as strings need to be quoted.  But don't just put quotes around "{0}" - the correct fix is to use a parametrized query and pass the StateId as a parameter.  Something like:

```
string sql = "select [CityName], [CityId] FROM Cities where StateId = @stateId"
cmd.Parameters.Add("stateId", stateId);
```

This is more efficient and protects you from [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).